# NodeJS: Auto-catch errors in Promise and call reject

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I recently found myself in a situation very difficult to debug.
Imagine the following very simple situation:

```
function somePromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        SomeModule.someMethod();
        AnotherModule.somePromise().then(resolve).catch(reject);
    });
}
```

Resolve was never called, but I didn't get an error in the console - this was difficult to debug!
Turns out that I forgot to require `SomeModule`. After requiring it, the code worked as expected.

Is there a way to automatically try/catch every Promise in my code with an error handler? I don't want to surround the body of my Promises with a try/catch block just to be able to find such errors more easily in the future.

Thanks in advance for opinions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to automatically try/catch every Promise in my code with an error handler?

This is implicitly done by the `Promise` constructor already. If the callback throws an exception synchronously, the promise will reject.

However, you really should avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! Use

```
function somePromise() {
    SomeModule.someMethod();
    return AnotherModule.somePromise();
}
```

Comment: This was just for simplification purposes, I do some more processing with the results of the promise which justifies the "antipattern".

Comment: No, there's no justification for the antipattern. Simply do `.then(processing)`, where `processing` is a function that takes the promise results and computes a new return value. Very likely mistakes in the processing were the actual reason why you didn't get any error messages.

Comment: They weren't, the issue was in the catch method of the method handling my own promise method. But thanks for your opinion.